# How can I find the equation of this Hyperbola?

Tags: conic-sections

I have drawn [a hyperbolic curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfRe2.png) on CAD software and apparently, the only information I seem to be able to get is that the rho value is 0.513. Do I have enough information to determine the equation of this curve?

Comment: If the leftmost point is a vertex and the tangent is horizontal there, then your curve has equation of the form $y = a(\sqrt{1 + b^{2}x^{2}} - 1)$ for some $a$ and $b$, so the other two points should enough to find $a$ and $b$.

Comment: What do you mean by "rho value"?

Comment: @Intelligentipauca the ratio between the vertex and the apex as shown [here](http://www.viewmold.com/ug_html_files/modeling/crv_2pt_anc.html)